# Div around img tag in Drupal 7

Tags: blocks, wysiwyg

I am using Drupal 7 with wysiwyg (7.x-2.0)module and CK editor 3.5.3.6655. I added an image in  a block with link and the CK editor code is

```
<p>
    <a class="thickbox" href="example.com"> [[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_original","fid":"751","attributes":{"alt":"contact","class":"media-image","typeof":"foaf:Image"}}]]</a>
</p>
```

But Drupal is adding some divs around the img tag and the resulting code is

```
<div id="block-block-11" class="block block-block">   
      <div class="content">
         <p>
            <a class="thickbox" href="example.com">
                <div class="field field-name-file field-type-file field-label-hidden">
                    <div class="field-items">
                        <div class="field-item even">
                            <span id="styles-0-0" class="styles file-styles original">
                                <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="path to image.jpg" alt="contact" />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
         </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Then I got the W3C error **document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "button", "map", "object", "ins", "del", "noscript" start-tag** as div is not allowed inside p and a. How can I solve this?

I added div instead of p but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The divs were added by the image module and the problem solved when I updated the module.

When adding an image through media file selector, click on image properties and remove the style sheet class value (media-image attr_*typeof*_foaf:Image img_*fid*_106 img__view_mode__media_original). This will show the image in img tag instead of some weird code

Answer (score 1):

This is a field themeing issue.  The [field.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--theme--field.tpl.php/7) API docs and linked source is a good place to start.  The comments on that page also have useful information for you.

Comment: Hill,are you talking about the fields in content-type ? I have this issue with adding full html content with some images into <structure->block-> Block add >

Comment: The divs were added by the image module and the problem solved when a I updated the module